# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot write xcontent for unknown value of type class java.util.UUID?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Hi I am using java high level rest api client to read some documents from an elastic search index and i am getting the following error .

I get this error when i do perform a request on elasticsearch client as below.

elasticSearchClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot write xcontent for unknown value of type class java.util.UUID
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.unknownValue(XContentBuilder.java:833)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:804)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.field(XContentBuilder.java:789)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.MatchQueryBuilder.doXContent(MatchQueryBuilder.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.toXContent(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder.doXArrayContent(BoolQueryBuilder.java:280)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder.doXContent(BoolQueryBuilder.java:261)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.toXContent(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:857)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:850)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.field(XContentBuilder.java:842)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.innerToXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:1182)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.toXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:1309)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.toXContent(XContentHelper.java:353)
```

Following is the content of my elastic search index .

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/mep-report-today/_search/?size=10"
{"took":9,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":100,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"k33fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4M","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"lH3fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4M","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"n33fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4M","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"oH3fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4M","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"oX3fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4M","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"on3fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4N","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"pH3fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4N","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"rn3fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4N","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"t33fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4N","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}},{"_index":"mep-report-today","_type":"doc","_id":"wX3fEW0B6qRb3bOs9s4N","_score":1.0,"_source":{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407000,"delivery_ts":1549246209000}}]}}
```

any idea what is the reason for this error.
I am using elastic search java rest client api version 6.6.1

really appreciate any help 
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have used toString() to solve this issue, messageHistoryFilterRequest.getAccountId() was returning a java.util.UUID . elastic search dont understand UUID . so once i do a toString() it got resolved

```
if (messageHistoryFilterRequest.getAccountId() != null) {
    MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("account_id",
            messageHistoryFilterRequest.getAccountId().toString());
    boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
}

if (messageHistoryFilterRequest.getCampaignId() != null) {
    MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("campaign_id",
            messageHistoryFilterRequest.getCampaignId().toString());
    boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
}

if (messageHistoryFilterRequest.getFlightId() != null) {
    MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("flight_id",
            messageHistoryFilterRequest.getFlightId().toString());
    boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
}
```